# Regarding passing pointers in C

Tags: c

I am new to C.
I am trying to build a data structure which stores 10 strings (which I call `commands` in the code comments).
Right now, it looks like I'm having trouble with my `insertCommand` function.  It looks like it's not inserting the commands.  I'm looking for where the bug as, as well as anything else that may be immediately wrong with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_COMMANDS 10
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100

struct commandStorage
{
    /* When initalizing an @commandStorage structure, one must set mostRecent = 0. */
    char stringArray[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    int mostRecent;
};

void insertCommand(struct commandStorage* addressOfcStore, char newCommand[])
{
    struct commandStorage cStore;
    cStore = *addressOfcStore;
    cStore.mostRecent++;

    if (cStore.mostRecent >= MAX_COMMANDS)
    {
        cStore.mostRecent = 0;
    }

    strncpy(cStore.stringArray[cStore.mostRecent], newCommand, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
}

void printRecentTen(struct commandStorage cStore)
{
    int inx;
    int i;
    inx = cStore.mostRecent;

    for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        if (cStore.stringArray[inx] == 0)
        continue;

        printf("%d %s\n", i, cStore.stringArray[inx]);
        inx -= 1;
        if (inx < 0)
        {
            inx = MAX_COMMANDS - 1;
        }
    }
}

char* retrieveMostRecent(struct commandStorage cStore)
{
    int mrInx = cStore.mostRecent;
    char *mrString;
    mrString = cStore.stringArray[mrInx];
    return mrString;
}

char* retrieveNth(struct commandStorage cStore, int n)
{
    int cmdInx = 0;
    cmdInx += cStore.mostRecent - n + 1;
    if (cmdInx < 0)
    {
        cmdInx = MAX_COMMANDS - cmdInx;
    }
    return cStore.stringArray[cmdInx];
}

int main()
{
    struct commandStorage thisStore;
    thisStore.mostRecent = 0;
    char* recentCommand;
    char one[3]  = "One";
    char two[3] = "Two";
    char three[5] = "Three";
    char four[4] = "Four";
    char five[5] = "Five";
    char six[3] = "Six";
    char seven[5] = "Seven";
    char eight[5] = "Eight";
    char nine[4] = "Nine";
    char ten[3] = "Ten";
    char eleven[6] = "Eleven";

    memset (&thisStore, 0, sizeof(thisStore));

    insertCommand(&thisStore, one);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, two);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, three);

    printRecentTen(thisStore);
    recentCommand = retrieveMostRecent(thisStore);
    printf("%s", recentCommand);

    insertCommand(&thisStore, four);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, five);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, six);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, seven);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, eight);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, nine);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, ten);
    insertCommand(&thisStore, eleven);

    printRecentTen(thisStore);
    recentCommand = retrieveMostRecent(thisStore);
    printf("%s", recentCommand);
    recentCommand = retrieveNth(thisStore, 3);
    printf("%s", recentCommand);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the (correct) answer below, please note that all your other functions have a very similar problem: You copy the input structure (implicitly by taking it by value). It wont hurt you in the print function, but it will in the retrieve* functions (because you return an address of a member of a local variable).

Comment: Also note that `strncpy` will not zero-terminate the string if the length hits the limit. Anyway, don't use `strncpy` for that purpose. Use `strlcpy`, if where available, or write your own version of `strlcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

All of your trouble has to do with making a copy of the input struct and then updating the copy rather than the one you passed in. Change as follows:

```
void insertCommand(struct commandStorage* addressOfcStore, char newCommand[])
{
    addressOfcStore->mostRecent++;
    if (addressOfcStore->mostRecent >= MAX_COMMANDS)
    {
       addressOfcStore->mostRecent = 0;
    }

    strncpy(addressOfcStore->stringArray[addressOfcStore->mostRecent],
            newCommand, 
            MAX_STRING_LENGTH);

}
```

Comment: As usual, any attempts to use `strncpy` for "safe" string copying will not produce good code, even if you take care of the potential "missing \0" issue.

Comment: Agreed but in straight C; what better choice do you have really?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I'm hard pressed to imagine a situation where gratuitously sacrificing the tail portion of the source string is an acceptable course of action. For which reason I generally don't believe that one needs this capability at all. But if you really want to go that way, the non-standard (and, possibly, manually implemented ) `strlcpy` is the way to go.

Comment: strlcpy still has to be implemented using something. strncpy is a good starting point for a strlcpy impl. I'm not saying I disagree with your sentiments, but these are the fundamentals and a good way to learn how they (don't) work is to try them and see :)

Comment: Well, OK. I'll just repeat that if one wants to use strncpy as a rough approximation of strlcpy in sketch-quality code, one still has to remember to perform manual zero-termination of the destination string.